# Validation against NumPy dtypes -- what's the least circuitous way to check values?

Tags: python, validation, numpy, introspection, typechecking

I want to test an unknown value against the constraints that a given NumPy `dtype` implies -- e.g., if I have an integer value, is it small enough to fit in a `uint8`?

As best I can ascertain, NumPy's `dtype` architecture doesn't offer a way to do something like this:

```
### FICTIONAL NUMPY CODE: I made this up ###
try:
    numpy.uint8.validate(rupees)
except numpy.dtype.ValidationError:
    print "Users can't hold more than 255 rupees."
```

My little fantasy API is based on Django's [model-field validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/), but that's just one example -- the best mechanism I managed to contrive was along the lines of this:

```
>>> nd = numpy.array([0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=numpy.dtype('uint8'))
>>> nd[0]
0
>>> nd[0] = 1
>>> nd[0] = -1
>>> nd
array([255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0], dtype=uint8)
>>> nd[0] = 257
>>> nd
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Round-tripping the questionable values through a `numpy.ndarray` typed as explicitly `numpy.uint8` gives me back integers that have been wrapped to something with an appropriate size -- without tossing an exception, or raising any other sort of actionable error state.

I'd rather not put on the architecture-astronaut flight suit, of course, but that's preferable the alternative, which looks like unmaintainable spaghetti-monster mess of `if dtype(this) ... elif dtype(that)` statements. Is there anything I can do here besides embarking on the grandiose and indulgent act of writing my own API?

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice for the 255 rupees limit.

Comment: Haha, thanks – rupees are what always comes to mind whenever I have to deal with 8-bit value alignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `a` is your original iterable, you could do something along the following lines:

```
np.all(np.array(a, dtype=np.int8) == a)
```

Quite simply, this compares the resulting `ndarray` to the original values, and tells you whether the conversion to `ndarray` has been lossless.

This will also catch things like using a floating-point type that's too narrow to represent some of the values exactly:

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.123456789]
>>> np.all(np.array(a, dtype=np.float32) == a)
False
>>> np.all(np.array(a, dtype=np.float64) == a)
True
```

**Edit:** One caveat when using the above code with floating-point numbers is that NaNs always compare unequal. If required, it is trivial to extend the code to handle that case too.

Comment: I'll take that -- your method is pretty handy and nonverbose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `numpy` [iinfo](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) / [finfo](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) structs. They should provide all the information needed for a validation service that works for elementary dtypes. This wont work for composite or binary field dtypes. You still would have to implement the service skeleton for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`numpy.seterr()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr) with `over` in order to trigger warnings/errors on overflow.

e.g.

```
numpy.seterr(over='raise')
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `np.seterr(over='raise'); np.uint8(257)` gives `1` without error.

Comment: Apologies, that's only checked during operations/arithmetic.